# Why was this useful answer that helped me deleted?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, deleted-answers, specific-answer, hyperlinks

This answer on my 8 month old question got deleted 7 months ago by a moderator: [Convert non-transparent image to transparent gif image PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61926262/13552470)

As far as I know, answers that go like this:

> Here is an article that provides the answer to your question: [link](https://www.not-a-real-link.com)

are disqualified, but answers that go like *this*:

> The answer to your question is to use this tool: [link](https://www.not-a-real-link.com)

are perfectly qualified. Am I mistaken?

Comment: for promotions you need also write your affiliation with it

Comment: the answer, only points to a side, wihich is a promotion, so the delete is besides that is is lowwquality for a cause delete

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question asked for how to *write code* using the Python Imaging Library to perform a specific task. The answer had nothing to do with answering the question. The "answer" was flagged as Not An Answer. The "answer" was, in fact, not an answer, so a moderator deleted it when responding to the flag.

The "answer" makes no attempt to actually answer the question of how to perform the task from a programming perspective, let alone using [python-imaging-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-imaging-library), which is what your question asks. *At best*, the "answer" is a comment, but it could legitimately be considered spam (unsolicited suggestion of using a service). It does not appear that the "answer" was intended as spam, or that the author was affiliated with the service and didn't disclose that affiliation, so it was merely deleted, rather than marked as spam.

Comment: Alternatively, if the question is meant to be interpreted as asking to how to convert an image as a once-off task, then the question is off-topic.  It is not a programming problem.  It should be asked on SuperUser instead.